# Rules for deriving correlations of alternate contrast coding schemes?

Tags: correlation, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

Imagine a hierarchical data scenario where each of multiple people are observed many times for each of combination of a two two-level (lo-vs-hi) predictor variables. If sum contrasts are used to encode the condition variable, then using lme4-style syntax we would write:

```
dv ~ 1 + V1*V2 + (1 + V1*V2 | person)
```

And that would yield a 4x4 correlation matrix, encoding correlations among the intercept, main effect of V1, main effect of V2, and the V1:V2 interaction.

Alternatively, one could recode the predictors with 4 contrasts that encode which combination of V1 & V2 each observation represents then model as:

```
dv ~ 0 + V1_lo_V2_lo + V1_lo_V2_hi + V1_hi_V2_lo + V1_hi_V2_hi +
    (0 + V1_lo_V2_lo + V1_lo_V2_hi + V1_hi_V2_lo + V1_hi_V2_hi | person)
```

Yielding again a 4x4 correlation matrix, this time encoding the correlations of the means of the conditions.

If one computed only this second model, is there any procedure for deriving the correlations that one would have obtained had the first model been fit? And vice versa? Or is this maybe an unsolveable thing where there's a one-to-many correspondence in either direction?